# Put custom links outside weblinks section

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

How can I put custom links outside the web links section in a salesforce page? 
Or is there a way I can create more than one weblinks section?

If not is there a way I can create a custom field that can call a javascript method ? (my custom links calls a js method that after validation will call a web service to do some work.)
I tried creating a custom field (formula) but I wasnt able to call a js function from there, or put some script.

What I want to do is spread my custom links I have in the weblinks section into different sections on the page.

Comment: I do not think it is possible. May be try to include a visualforce page for that or use a custom button?

Comment: @mast0r can a visualforce page allow the user to modify fields like a default page ?

Comment: Generally yes, if you put `apex:detail` with `inlineEdit="true"` to the normal visualforce page. But you mean a visualforce page included to the standard salesforce layout page? I don't think so, because included VF-Page is an iFrame, and you can't access a parent page from the iFrame.

Comment: @mast0r yea, this is what I meant(to include a visualforce page in a standard layout page)... so this means I cant do that? there's no other workaround that will allow me to mix custom fields and custom links in the same section in a page layout? :\

Comment: You need "something" that will modify the standard page layout on the load. A custom button? Nope, because it fires an JS-action only on click. Custom page included? Nope, because of JavaScript security setting. Related lists and custom fields can't do that too :(

Comment: @mast0r Ok.... I'm wondering if I create a custom page and add custom fields and the custom links inside it and then add this page to the standard layout page.. Am I able to edit the custom fields the same way they are edited in the standard page?

Comment: Wow great idea! Try to do it with inlineEditSupport. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this method to override link and button actions in the past. You could use the same method for move elements around the page too.

Create a visualforce page and use it to override the standard page for the object you want to modify. The override page needs to use the standardcontroller for that object. You can use an extension controller for adding Apex functionality if necessary.

Use the detail tag to render the guts. Then put in a script tag to select the anchor links you want to move around the page. It will take some inspection with your browsers debugger to find exactly what you are looking for.

```
<apex:page StandardController="CustomObject__c" extensions="CustomObjectController"  >
    <apex:detail relatedList="false" inlineEdit="true" id="mydetail" />
    <script>
         // select your elements you want to move, edit or delete here
    </script>
</apex:page>
```